# Replace <div> with another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I'm working on an HTML page (*a template*) using `jQuery`, `CSS`, `HTML` without server-side and I have a problem when I want to do to replace a `<div>` with another HTML page from my computer.

On the main page i have this code:

```
<nav>
    <h2 class="hidden">Our navigation</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="nextpage(1);">Home</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="nextpage(2);>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="pageContent">
        Hello motto
        </div>
```

and JavaScript block is this:

```
function nextpage(idd){
$.get( "pages/page1.html", function( data ) {
  $("pageContent").html(data);
});

}
```

When I push "Home" button then must replace content of `pageContent` with the HTML code from my website-s root address: `../../pages/page1.html`.

I tried to implement these examples and withour any good result:

- [Replace current html page with ajax response](http://www.coderanch.com/t/510276/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Replace-current-html-page-ajax)
- [How to get source code of html page using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742534/how-to-get-source-code-of-html-page-using-jquery)
- [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

I want to replace a DIV without using Server-Side API's.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simple `$("#pageContent").load("pages/page1.html");`?

Comment: You should check out the jQuery [`load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)... it'll let you target elements within the loaded content as well, e.g. `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`

Comment: Satpal, because doesn't work both .load() and $.get()

Answer (score 3):

You misssed the `#` for id selector:

```
$("#pageContent").html(data);
```

---

Other than this you can use `.load()` method for it, because you can target specific div to load in your page you can do this:

```
$("#pageContent").load('pages/page1.html #divid2load');
// will load the #divid2load div from the html page.
```

Comment: I rewrote a simplified version and forgot to insert "#".

Comment: On debugger value of data is empty and I receive following error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/JOHN/DesktopTEMPLATE/pages/page1.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Alyunuzzu seems you are not working on a webserver, ajax runs on a webserver so try configuring on local webserver.

Comment: You are coding on the file protocol...bad idea.

Comment: I wish no longer give information copied from tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be placed on a web server then executed.
For security reasons normally browsers don't allow file:/// protocol for AJAX calls.
See here for your error [error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479694/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr)

As you asked server less i don't have experience on my own, but read about it, run your chrome instance with `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files` [More Explanation Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file)

Hope this Helps..........

Comment: Without Server-Side if possible

Comment: Not tried in my own but read about this $.ajaxPrefilter( "json script", function( options ) {
  options.crossDomain = true;
});  See Here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file

Comment: @Alynuzzu - You don't need server-side code, but you do need a *web server* to go about it using AJAX. The web server will be able to take requests and return responses in a way that the AJAX understands and can work with. If you're ever going to put there somewhere where other people can access it, file protocol isn't going to work, anyway, so you might as well do it the way that's going to work from the get-go.